# mongoose: how to insert into a field that is an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know how to push into an array that has objects, but in my case I have a field that is an array. so how do I insert data into that field? I need to insert data in the coordinates field.

schema:

```
 locations: [
        {
            type: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Point',
                enum: ['Point']
            },
            coordinates: [Number],
            address: String,
            description: String,
            day: Number
        }
    ]
```

I could insert data into the address field of the locations array but how do I add data in the coordinates field?

```
exports.updateTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
                toUpdate = mapTours({}, req.body)
                let tour = Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, toUpdate, {
                    runValidators: true,
                    new: true
                })
                .then(async doc => {
                        if (req.body.locations) {
                            if(req.body.locations.address) {
                        await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
                                $push: {
                                    locations: { address: req.body.locations.address }
                                }
                            })
                            if(req.body.locations.longitude && req.body.locations.latitude) {
                            await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
                                **how do I add into the coordinates array**
                            })
                        }
                        }
                        res.status(200).json({
                            status: 'success',
                            doc
                        })
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) `$`:

```
await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $push: {
           locations.$.coordinates: {$each: [req.body.locations.longitude, req.body.locations.latitude]}
        }
})
```